# How to store only AI responses in memory when using langchain?

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

My current code looks like this:

```
import os

import pandas as pd
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate

from langchain.document_loaders import DataFrameLoader
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores.faiss import FAISS

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(".env")

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
data = {

    'index': ['001', '002', '003'],
    'text': [
        'title: cats like jumping on the bed.',
        'title: dogs like walking on the beach.',
        'title: birds like flying in the sky.'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
loader = DataFrameLoader(df, page_content_column="text")
docs = loader.load()

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
retriever = FAISS.from_documents(docs, embeddings).as_retriever(k=4)

# llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.7, model_name="gpt-4-1106-preview", max_tokens=4096)
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.7, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106", max_tokens=4096)

template = """
Use the following context (delimited by <ctx></ctx>) to answer the question. Make sure that you don't generate similar data to what you already generated (delimited by <ar></ar>).
------
<ctx>
{context}
</ctx>
------
<ar>
{ai_responses}
</ar>
------
{question}
Answer:
"""
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["ai_responses", "context", "question"],
    template=template,
)

# memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="history", return_messages=True)

chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=llm,
    chain_type='stuff',
    retriever=retriever,
    verbose=True,
    chain_type_kwargs={
        "verbose": True,
        "prompt": prompt,
        "memory": ConversationBufferMemory(
            memory_key="ai_responses",
            input_key="question")
    }
)

while True:
    question = input("Ask a question: ")
    print(chain.run({"query": question}))
```

For now memory stores both User and Ai responses. I want to somehow store only responses given by AI. Howcan I do that based on this example? I want to guide the model not to geneerate similar data/facts later when chatting with it and in this case User messages are not needed inside memory.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an elegant way, but for me, I just extract AI response and write it back to memory.

```
def replace_mem():
  AImem = []
  for index,value in enumerate(memory.dict()['chat_memory']['messages']):
    if value['type']=='ai':
      AImem.append(memory.dict()['chat_memory']['messages'][index]['content'])

  #Clear memory here
  memory.clear() 

  for ai_mem in AImem:
    memory.chat_memory.add_ai_message(ai_mem)
```